# Vetoing a CDI bean for web-app context only

Tags: java, glassfish-3, cdi, ear, deltaspike

I am running an EAR module on Glassfish 3.1.2.2 and am experiencing an issue where Deltaspike is creating two instances of a bean (one in the ejb module and one in the web module).

I would like to veto this bean in the web module

```
public class VetoAnnotatedTypeExtension implements Extension {

    public <T> void processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<T> type) {
        if (something?) {
            type.veto();
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a predicate for the `something?` that I can use to veto when in the web-app context?

Comment: I dont get the term "to veto" in this context. What should happen?

Comment: See http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/enterprise/inject/spi/ProcessAnnotatedType.html#veto()

Comment: It sounds more like an issue with your setup and not DeltaSpike itself.

Answer (score 0):

Ears always get tricky. You could check the classloader of the class and see where it's coming from. That's probably the only reliable thing you could do.